# Display WooCommerce notice in pop up

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

How can I display a custom WooCommerce notice in a pop up for all calls to `wc_add_notice`?

```php
if (!$product_data -> is_started()) {
    wc_add_notice(sprintf(__('Sorry, the auction for &quot;%s&quot; has not started yet', 'wc_simple_auctions'), $product_data -> get_title()),'error');
    return false;
}

// Stock check - only check if we're managing stock and backorders are not allowed
if (!$product_data -> is_in_stock()) {
    wc_add_notice(sprintf(__('You cannot place a bid for &quot;%s&quot; because the product is out of stock.', 'wc_simple_auctions'), $product_data -> get_title()),'error');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pop up"?

Comment: normal woocommerce will show notice same as this link https://i1.wp.com/businessbloomer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/woocommerce-remove-was-successfully-added-to-cart-message1.jpg?w=933&ssl=1     but i want it show in pop up insteed of warning text

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the `wc_print_notices` placement in your theme. In the theme, you'll probably want to wrap `wc_print_notices` with a container for your lightbox/pop-up to control it's display.